Why is $\Gamma$ Commonly Used/Taught Instead of $\Pi$ as an Extension of the Factorial?
The Gamma function is often described as an extension of the factorial function. Why do we call it this when the function is shifted from the factorial? We already have a function ($\Pi(z)$) describing the same thing but without the transposition.
The $n-1$ in $\Gamma(n)=\int_0^{\infty}t^{n-1}e^{-t}\,dt$ seems unnecessary to me, only causing extra confusion.
I don't understand why we make it more complicated with the shift when we already have the Pi function. I have seen textbooks that use $\Gamma(z)$ on every other page yet don't even mention $\Pi(z)$. Why is this?

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/20960/why-is-the-gamma-function-shifted-from-the-factorial-by-1

Capital pi is also used to express general products, so a certain amount of disambiguation would be needed to express a similar function to $\Gamma$ "without the trans[lation]".  Note also the use of pi in prime counting.  Sometimes the overloading of a symbol can be too much of a good thing.

That just seems more of an argument to use a different symbol for the function, than a problem with the function itself, to be fair.

Complex analysis:  the integrand in $$\Gamma(n) = \int_0^{\infty } e^{-t} \  t^{n-1} \, dt$$ has its  defining simple pole $\frac{e^{-t}}{t} \to \frac{1}{t} $ in the origin.
$\Gamma$ essentially simplifies formula by $\Re z>0$, saves many $(-1)$.
For fast formual perception $\Gamma$ distinguishes it from $\Pi(n)=n!$ that classically was assumed to be an integer function showing up in every Taylor formula  and in binomial expressions.
Its use is a hint for the domain of an equality in the complex plane.
